# Can a neutrino act as a virtual particle between two electrons to mediate an electron-electron fermonic interaction?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, neutrinos

Can a neutrino act as a virtual particle between two electrons to mediate electron-electron fermonic interaction analogous to how a photon acts as a virtual particle between two electrons to mediate a bosonic electron-electron interaction?

What would the Lagrangian look like for an electron-electron interaction mediated by neutrinos?

Comment: Neutrinos are fermions like electrons. There can be no $ee\nu$ vertex -- this is not possible as it would violate conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: @suresh I apologize for my generalization. I should have said two neutrinos instead, which I think would conserve angular momentum.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then, Kyle's answer will do as the loop diagram involving two $e\nu W$ vertices will work. In other words, such a process does NOT need new terms in the SM lagrangian. If you want effective Lagrangians, it will look like a four-fermi interaction after integrating out the W-bosons with the coupling constant proportional to $G_F^2$ ($G_F$ is the Fermi constant)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on my qed, but I'll give this a shot. The simplest case would be described by a diagram similar to:

[image]

But the $e^--e^--\nu_e$ vertex doesn't exist (also note that I can't draw the required arrow on the neutrino) - the vertices of the standard model (with the exception of vertices involving the Higgs and neutrino oscillations) are:

[image]

With these, the closest interaction to what you describe that I can see is:

[image]

There are virtual neutrinos as you specified, but also virtual $W$ bosons.
If you rotate that diagram 90 degrees, there's an $e^--e^+$ scattering mediated by virtual neutrinos and $W$ bosons, but again, not quite what you asked for.

Comment: If anyone less rusty than me could give that a quick once over and leave a comment if there are any glaring errors, would be appreciated. Would be nice just to know roughly how much I retained from when I tried learning particle physics.

Comment: I think it looks good - but why do you say that the neutrinos in your bottom diagram are not virtual? As internal lines, they seem to be more or less by definition virtual.

Comment: @Kyle I think your saying that a W boson is required for the interaction. Thanks for the answer. What would the Lagrangian look like for two electrons?

Comment: @linuxfreebird: Lagrangian are not things accompanying specific interactions, they are the general principle from which the interactions arise. The "Lagrangian for 2 electrons" is the same as the Lagrangian for any other particle of the Standard Model, it is (a subset of) the Standard Model Lagrangian.

Comment: This is correct. It's called a "box diagram." It'll be a tiny effect, though. In an [upcoming $e$-$e$ weak interaction experiment](http://hallaweb.jlab.org/12GeV/Moller/), the expected asymmetry due to interference between electromagnetic repulsion and $Z^0$ exchange is predicted to be about 35 parts per billion (that is, flip a coin a billion times, get 35 more tails than heads). If we handwave that the $e$-$W$ coupling is as strong as the $e$-$Z$ coupling, this interaction would contribute an asymmetry around $(35\times10^{-9})^2 \approx 10^{-15}$. Not experimentally accessible.

Comment: fine, except that any internal line in a Feynman diagram is by definition virtual, so yes, neutrinos in the final box diagram are virtual

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ACuriousMind and anna v and rob :)

Comment: Is a W-boson a massive charged particle with spin 1 or spin zero?

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for providing the diagrams. Are there only two electrons or four electrons the diagrams?

Comment: @Kyle Wait a minute. I think there is a small problem with your diagram. In order to conserve charge, the W-bosons would have to be of opposite charge.

Comment: Although on reflection, it occurs to me that the tiny asymmetry I estimated due to this $W$-$W$ box diagram is for an experiment where the momentum transfer is very small — precisely because that experiment is aimed at getting a "clean" measurement. If the momentum transfer is large compared with the $W$ mass, it may become the case that all the electroweak box diagrams ($\gamma$-$\gamma$, $\gamma$-$Z$, $Z$-$Z$, $W$-$W$) contribute at roughly the same level. That'd be an interesting follow-up question.

Comment: @linuxfreebird The $W$ boson is massive with unit spin. There are four electron "legs" on the diagram, because two electrons go in and two go out; because electrons are all identical, you don't get the luxury of asking whether one of your incoming electrons is "the same" as one of your outgoing electrons. If you look carefully you will notice that there's no charge indicated on the $W$ lines; in a real calculation you'd do an integral over all the possible $W$ momenta, including both $e^-\to\nu W^-$ and $e^- W^+\to\nu$ at each incoming electron vertex.

Comment: @rob I hate that sort of coin flip analogy - if you flip a billion coins, you expect to be off of 50/50 by way more than 35 coins, can't ignore the variance. But I get what you mean, anything involving too many weak interactions where there are stronger interaction alternatives is prohibitively unlikely.

Comment: @Kyle, the variance in uncorrelated events goes like $\sqrt N$, where $N$ is the number of events. So to see a part-per-billion asymmetry without getting swamped by statistical fluctuations, you have to do roughly $10^{18}$ coinflips. But that didn't fit in the character limit of my previous comment. :-)